# knife ssh command -X user: how to automatically specify user according to node platform

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife

I have CentOS and Ubuntu chef nodes, due to OS deployment process, there are no common ssh user name among them (But they do accept a common SSH user private key)

So to run knife ssh to them, I have to specify different user for them:

```
knife ssh "platform:centos" "command" -x userX
knife ssh "platform:ubuntu" "command" -x userY
```

How can I let knife use appropriate ssh user name according to node platform like this:

```
knife ssh name:* "command" -x '${node['platform']=='centos'?'userX':'userY'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need something more complex than `knife ssh` for that. Check out scripted SSH clients like Fabric, Invoke, and Capistrano. Or you could use a lower-level library like Ruby's net-ssh (which is what `knife ssh` is built on).